# How do I set up my own "virtual private network" to evade Internet censorship in China?

Tags: networking, vpn, proxy

I am a Chinese-Canadian and live in Canada. I will go to China for a couple of weeks and due to censorship in that country, I will not be able to access a lot of sites while there. Proxy server software do not seem to work well the last time I went to China in 2017.

I have a desktop here in Canada with fast Internet access. Is there a way for me to create a system that, before I go to China, I leave the desktop computer on 24/7 for weeks--where when I am in China and go on the Internet there, I use my computer to connect to the Canadian computer (which has no Internet restrictions)? Besides using TeamViewer or other remote desktop software, what other options do we have?

Comment: What are the penalties when you get caught circumventing censorship?

Comment: USD $15 fine, it seems.

Comment: In China?......

Comment: plus life in prison

Comment: No, I would probably be deported to Canada, since I am not actually a Chinese citizen any longer.